# Best solution to merge/include an xml layout file multiple times in an activity layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a flashcards app as a college project, and wanted a horizontally scrolling display of the cards. I've built an xml file for the flashcard design itself:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/whitenote" android:padding="3dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonPins"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="@color/transparent" android:src="@drawable/pinselector"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewWord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Word" android:textColor="@color/black" android:paddingTop="30dp" android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMeaning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewWord"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Meaning" android:textColor="@color/black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've also created the Class file.

In the activity layout, I have a few more elements and as such a linearlayout at the root level is necessary. I've been able to display a single flashcard for test purposes using  and using layout inflater.

**Question**
In both the ways, in  and layout inflater I've been unable to get the ImageButton working. My question is how do I get the button to work.

**Update: Managed to get the ImageButton working using . Realised that I have to handle the onclick event in the activity, and not the Custom Adapter class. This should allow me to obtain the words too, as long as I can keep track of the "current" flashcard on display**

Also, whats the best way to handle the scrolling for a flashcard app? My current plans so far is to use a HorizontalScrollView and customise it a bit, because I need (a) a swipe should make the flashcard move only to the next one (b) I need to focus on the "current" flashcard since I need some data from its children views (ie, the word).

Comment: How is the `ImageButton` not working? Is it not visible? Is it not responding? What's wrong and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Kabuko: I've managed to get the button working now. It wasn't responding to click events, which I realised must be handled in the activity class and not the Custom Adapter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you considering Fragments?

You can get some help with the ViewPager here.This is supported in Android 3.0 or above or Android 1.6 with the compatibility package.

> http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html

If you do not wish to use the fragments, you can simply use the Gallery. This way, you can achieve the horizontal scrolling. (like in the Amazon app) without complex ViewPager.

Comment: ViewPager is how I've gone, and though all three suggested that, I'm giving you the correct answer because of the example you linked which was extremely helpful. Thanks a ton, everyone

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, take a look at the [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out immediately

Answer (score 1):

A `HorizontalScrollView` or a `Gallery` are probably the most direct way of implementing this.  I don't use `Gallery`-- but it is good to at least know it exists.

If you want a *much* more robust implementation, I agree with dcanh121 and think you should check out a `Fragment` based `ViewPager`.  This will allow more options than just a View , but might be overkill depending on the goal.  A `fragment` is *basically* the bizarre offspring of an `Activity` and a `View`, but don't quote me on that.

Also,

Inflating layouts is costly, so try to only inflate the XML into a `View` once, and reuse that `View` object.  Try not to re-inflate the XML every time a new flashcard is drawn.